# Error while loading dataset in R-fiddle

Tags: r

How can i load datasets in my code when using R-fiddle.
I tried getting it from a url but there were some errors

http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=S4A74L4E

Comment: why is this being voted closed?  It is a reasonable question IMO

Comment: @LegalizeIt I think it's due to insufficient information of what dataset and error.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to upload your data to publicly visible url.  Here is an example where I put the output from some data (`dput(dat)`) onto [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/hPN1GLyw).  `rvest` isn't available on R fiddle apparently, but using `XML` library, you can then scrape the data from the pastebin page.

```
library(XML)
mydat <- "http://pastebin.com/hPN1GLyw"

stuff <- htmlParse(mydat)

li <- getNodeSet(stuff, "//div[@class=\'text\']")
dat <- eval(parse(text=xmlSApply(li, xmlValue)))

dat
#    lodi dodi
# 1     1   10
# 2     2    9
# 3     3    8
# 4     4    7
# 5     5    6
# 6     6    5
# 7     7    4
# 8     8    3
# 9     9    2
# 10   10    1
```

Comment: I was able to use this method to load data into RStudio, but not r-fiddle.org. There was a general error with the R session. Perhaps it was too much data. Are there any good alternatives for R-fiddle where it's not necessary to sign up for an account?